# How to Select value with condition on another column

Tags: sql, sqlite

| OrgID | EmpID | Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Sam | A |
| 1 | 2 | Gel | B |
| 2 | 1 | Moy | A |
| 2 | 2 | Gar | A |

`tbl_AGE` has 4 columns `OrgID`, `EmpID`, `Name`, `Status`.

I want to display `OrgID` values whose all `EmpID` status is 'A'.

So if any of `EmpID` has status 'B' then `OrgID` value should not be printed. To display `OrgID`, all respective `EmpID` should meet status criteria.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to only return organisations whose employees *all* have salaries of 1000 or above?

If that's the case, the following will achieve that:

```
SELECT  OrgID
  FROM  tbl_AGE
  WHERE OrgID NOT IN (
                     SELECT  OrgID
                       FROM  tbl_AGE
                       WHERE Salary < 1000
                       GROUP BY OrgID
                     )
  GROUP BY OrgID
```

This uses an `NOT IN` clause to remove any organisation that has any employee whose salary is below 1000.

Here's a [working fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fLiJR1JRTjNrNaybWxTzRY/0) showing this in action.

### Edit following OP update to question

OP changes the question to remove the `Salary` column and instead use a `Status` column.

The principle remains the same - filter out the unwanted `OrgID` values and return the remainder:

```
SELECT  OrgID
  FROM  tbl_AGE
  WHERE OrgID NOT IN (
                     SELECT  OrgID
                       FROM  tbl_AGE
                       WHERE Status = 'B'
                       GROUP BY OrgID
                     )
  GROUP BY OrgID
```

Here's a [revised working fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fLiJR1JRTjNrNaybWxTzRY/1) showing this working.

Comment: I have updated question. please check now.

Comment: @Adityasharma I've updated the answer to answer your revised question now instead.

Comment: @Adityasharma Great. Perhaps you could upvote my answer or mark it as correct then?

Comment: I need one more condition in this query. I've one column value named threshold, if threshold value is 0 then no need to execute where clause otherwise we have to execute where clause.
How can i do this?

Comment: @Adityasharma You need to raise a new question for that.  And btw you need to choose a correct answer too to your first question

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67587544/how-to-select-value-with-multiple-conditions

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest aggregation:

```
select orgId
from t
group by orgId
having max(status) = 'A';
```

You can make this a bit more general (i.e. not relying on `'A' < 'B'`) using:

```
having sum(case when status <> 'A' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

I would recommend `NOT EXISTS` if you wanted the original records:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.orgid = t.orgid and t2.status <> 'A'
                 );
```

Comment: I need one more condition in this query. I've one column value named threshold, if threshold value is 0 then no need to execute where clause otherwise we have to execute where clause.
How can i do this?

Comment: @Adityasharma . . . This answers the question you originally asked.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`select orgid from tlb_age where orgid not in ( select orgid from tbl_age where status <> 'A')`

Comment: This will return the same `orgid` on more than one row