# How to select value with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

tbl_A has 4 columns OrgID, EmpID, Time, Status and tbl_B has 2 columns OrgID, Threshold.
Condition:

1. If Threshold Time (from tbl_A) is greater than current time that OrgID should be printed.

There may be multiple EmpIDs for one OrgID so we have to check validation one by one if 1st EmpID (under of same OrgID) validates Time is greater then current time then no need to check for 2nd EmpID just print OrgID directly.

tbl_status:

```
OrgID   EmpID   Time                         Status  
100     1       2021-05-18 00:00:00.000       A     
100     2       2021-05-18 00:00:00.000       B   
100     3       2021-05-18 00:00:00.000       A
200     1       2021-05-18 00:00:00.000       A      
200     2       2021-05-18 00:00:00.000       A
```

tbl_hold:

```
OrgID  Threshold
100       0
200       10
```

IF Threshold is 0 then it does not validate any condition just print OrgID but if There is threshold value then it should first check for first EmpID and if qualify then no need to check condition for rest EmpIDs.

Output:

```
OrgID
100
200
```

Because for OrgID 100, i first check Threshold value which is 0 so no need any condition simply it will be printed.
But OrgID 200 has threshold so i checked there are 2 EmpIDs for it. so first i did validation for first EmpID of 200 OrgID and it validated condition and it worked.

Comment: Perhaps use better names that it is easier to follow along

Comment: your second condition explanation is not clear , try to explain it better .also provide desired output

Comment: What is the condition?  The mystery in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT a.OrgID
FROM tbl_A a
  INNER JOIN tbl_B b
    ON a.OrgID = b.OrgID
WHERE b.Threshold = 0
   OR DATEDIFF(minute, GETDATE(), a.Time) > b.Threshold
```

Comment: Thanks, please check updated question i have updated conditions.

Comment: @Adityasharma what's the unit for the threshold, minutes, hours, days?

Comment: As you provide answers, other people come to look on similar.  instead of just GIVING the answer, you should edit post and give the what / WHY you did.  Even a simple explanation that you know the join to the threshold table, but need to compare its time difference, blah, blah.  Also consider for future as well.

Comment: I used to have the explanation here but now, after a few rounds of clarification, it became so straightforward so I'm not even sure what comment to add